# check if div is certain html content then replace with new html

Tags: javascript, html

```
<div id="accordion" class="ui-accordion ui-widget ui-helper-reset" role="tablist">
 No items found.
</div>
```

I know this is probably simple, I'm just awful at JS. I would like to check the above div, and if it has 'No items found.' the I would like this to be replaced with 'We currently have no positions vacant however, please complete an expression of interest form if you would like to join our team'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var toReplace = 'No items found';
var replaceWith = 'We currently have no positions vacant however, please complete an expression of interest form if you would like to join our team';

var div = document.getElementById('accordion');
if (-1 !== div.innerHTML.indexOf(toReplace)) { // -1 if match not found, else >= 0
  div.innerHTML = replaceWith;
}
```

```html
<div id="accordion" class="ui-accordion ui-widget ui-helper-reset" role="tablist">
  No items found.
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Arvind I had to add a link into the new message that is replaced and it put weird styling on a <a> tag so I've amended your code slightly and it works great, thanks so much !!

Answer (score 1):

```js
(function() {
  // Store accordion in a variable because we're using it multiple times
  var accordion = document.getElementById("accordion");

  // Trim any excess white space
  var content = accordion.innerHTML.trim();

  var old_message = "No items found.";
  var new_message = "We currently have no positions vacant however, please complete an expression of interest form if you would like to join our team";
  
  if (content === old_message) {
    accordion.innerHTML = new_message;
  }
}());
```

```html
<div id="accordion" class="ui-accordion ui-widget ui-helper-reset" role="tablist">
 No items found.
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var aDiv = document.getElementById("accordion");
if (aDiv.innerHTML = " No items found.")
   aDiv.innerHTML = "We currently have no positions vacant however, please complete an expression of interest form if you would like to join our team";
```

Comment: The code does change the value of the div, but I have a Job Listing activated in the #accordian div and this is being removed and replaced with the message too

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jQuery you can simply do this:

```
var $ = jQuery.noConflict();

var accordion = $('#accordion');
if(accordion.html() == 'No items found.'){
  accordion.html('We currently have no positions vacant however, please complete an expression of interest form if you would like to join our team');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey Jake I'm pretty junior myself but I think if you do try to console.log the following let content = document.getElementById("accordion").innerHTML it should do it I'm going to test it myself momentarily.